# How to match alpha numeric cells to defined formats

Tags: string, google-sheets, extract

I am trying to build a sheet to differentiate certain part numbers by vendor format.

ex.

```
FORMAT           VENDOR
----------    -------------
XXXXX-XXX     EXAMPLE 1
XX-XXXXX-XX   EXAMPLE 2
    
PN            VENDOR
--------      --------------
12345-123     FIND VENDOR
12-12345-12   FIND VENDOR
```

Basically, I want it to match the format of a  pn cell and output the format that matches the vender..

any ideas?  i know regex can do it but im having a hard time getting it too work. This is what I tried for the first example.

```
=REGEXMATCH(A6, "[{5}][-]\d{3}")
```

But it just outputs `FALSE`. How can I make it to work, where it will find the matching pattern?

Comment: *"im having a hard time getting it too work"*: can you focus your question on your attempt (include it) and what went wrong with it?

Comment: This is what i tried for the first example. =REGEXMATCH(A6, "[{5}][-]\d{3}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGREPLACE`:

```
=XLOOKUP(REGEXREPLACE(A6,"\d","X"), A2:A3, B2:B3)
```

Here `A2:A3` refers to the range with the patterns, and `B2:B3` to the range with the vendor names that correspond to the patterns.

`\d` is the regular expression to match a digit. Each digit is replaced with an "X" so that you get a pattern. `XLOOKUP` will try to find the pattern and return the corresponding vendor.

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly.  Now what would the regex be for if it starts with a certain format?

Comment: Then instead of finding a match, find a substring. But if you have follow up questions, then just post a new question. But make sure to try first and include your attempt when you can't make it work.